# How many people have to be in a group so that the probability of at least one of them is left-handed is 0.9?

Tags: probability

In average 2% of the population is left-handed. How many people have to be in a group so that the probability of at least one of them being left-handed is 0.9?
I tried by calculating the complement and using conditional probabilty but got stuck.

Comment: Show your work up to the point that you got stuck, and I’m sure someone will unstick you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you just need the complement of what you are looking for (at least one being left-handed), which is to have all of them to be right handed.

Notice that the probability for a group of $n$ people to all be right handed is:

$$0.98^n$$

So you are simply looking for the complement of this event, i.e. you want a value of $n$ such that

$$1 - 0.98^n > 0.9 $$

Which works out easily to be:

\begin{align} \text{ln } 0.1 &> n \text{ln } 0.98 \\
n &> \frac{\text{ln}0.1}{\text{ln} 0.98} \approx 113.9
\end{align}
Thus, $n = 114$.